# Why Java 8 stream forEach loop is duplicating results after usage of sorted() method

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

During exercises with anagrams I have found out that my code after execution has duplicates in output depending on usage moment of `sorted()` method from `Stream` class.

When I'm doing sorting before `filter()` and `forEach()` methods

```
        words.stream()
                .sorted()
                .filter(s1 -> !alreadyFound.contains(s1) && words.stream()
                        .filter(s2 -> isAnagram.apply(s1, s2))
                        .count() == maxAnagrams)
                .forEach(s1 -> {
```

It is giving those results:

```
 abel able bale bela elba
 alger glare lager large regal
 angel angle galen glean lange
 caret carte cater crate trace
 elan lane lean lena neal
 evil levi live veil vile
```

But when I'm using `sorted()` after `filter()` and before `forEach()` methods

```
        words.stream()
                .filter(s1 -> !alreadyFound.contains(s1) && words.stream()
                        .filter(s2 -> isAnagram.apply(s1, s2))
                        .count() == maxAnagrams)
                .sorted()
```

Then it is giving those results:

```
 abel able bale bela elba
 abel able bale bela elba
 alger glare lager large regal
 angel angle galen glean lange
 angel angle galen glean lange
 abel able bale bela elba
 abel able bale bela elba
 caret carte cater crate trace
 caret carte cater crate trace
 caret carte cater crate trace
 caret carte cater crate trace
 elan lane lean lena neal
 abel able bale bela elba
 evil levi live veil vile
 angel angle galen glean lange
 alger glare lager large regal
 angel angle galen glean lange
 alger glare lager large regal
 elan lane lean lena neal
 angel angle galen glean lange
 alger glare lager large regal
 elan lane lean lena neal
 elan lane lean lena neal
 evil levi live veil vile
 evil levi live veil vile
 elan lane lean lena neal
 alger glare lager large regal
 caret carte cater crate trace
 evil levi live veil vile
 evil levi live veil vile
```

Is seems that in second approach program is duplicating results and adding already found words to the output. I wonder why is it happen?

I'm using:

```
jdk1.8.0_201
```

Example code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> alreadyFound = new ArrayList<>();

        BiFunction<String, String, Boolean> isAnagram = (s1, s2) -> {
            if (s1.length() != s2.length()) return false;
            char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();
            char[] c2 = s2.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(c1);
            Arrays.sort(c2);
            return Arrays.equals(c1, c2);
        };

        try (InputStream inputStream = new URL("http://wiki.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt").openStream();
             InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
             Stream<String> stream = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader).lines()) {
            stream.forEach(words::add);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        long maxAnagrams = Collections.max(words.stream()
                .map(s1 -> words.stream()
                        .filter(s2 -> isAnagram.apply(s1, s2))
                        .count())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
        words.stream()
//                .sorted()
                .filter(s1 -> !alreadyFound.contains(s1) && words.stream()
                        .filter(s2 -> isAnagram.apply(s1, s2))
                        .count() == maxAnagrams)
//                .sorted()
                .forEach(s1 -> {
                    alreadyFound.add(s1);
                    words.stream()
                            .filter(s2 -> isAnagram.apply(s1, s2))
                            .forEach(s2 -> {
                                alreadyFound.add(s2);
                                System.out.print(" " + s2);
                            });
                    System.out.println();
                });
    }
}
```

**// EDIT: OFF TOPIC**
I believe it is the best way to achieve desired results:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try (InputStream inputStream = new URL("http://wiki.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt").openStream();
             InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
             Stream<String> stream = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader).lines()) {
            List<List<String>> anagrams = new ArrayList<>(stream
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> {
                        char[] chars = o.toCharArray();
                        Arrays.sort(chars);
                        return new String(chars);
                    }))
                    .values());
            int maxAnagrams = anagrams.parallelStream()
                    .mapToInt(List::size)
                    .max()
                    .orElse(0);
            anagrams.stream()
                    .filter(strings -> strings.size() == maxAnagrams)
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.get(0)))
                    .forEach(strings -> {
                        strings.forEach(s -> System.out.print(s + " "));
                        System.out.println();
                    });
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(stop - start);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I could count the brackets correct, you have a stream inside a stream operation and I can see 2 `System.out` as well. What is it that you expect otherwise?

Comment: It might make your life a tad easier if you break that inner stream out into its own function.  I like the use of the BiFunction, but without having that filter condition as a predicate, it's a bit of a chore to parse.

Comment: I believe there is something happening in your filter that is causing it to remove duplicates if you sort it first - but in the second one that isn't happening.  I was doing a bit of playing with this to re-write it, but I'm getting the same duplication you are seeing.

Comment: You have created code relying on the *processing order* of the stream; your filter predicate assumes it can assume that the previous element has been already processed by `forEach`. This is broken by definition and as you can see, will break in practice in some scenarios, like when using `sorted()` or a parallel stream. Besides, your code doing repeated linear searches, even redundantly, is horribly inefficient. Generally, you should rethink your habit of using `forEach` for everything, starting with how to collect a stream into a `List`…

Comment: Thanks for all replies, regarding "efficiency" I have added better solution for this problem :) Regarding the problem as described bellow, algorithm presented above is sensitive for operation like `sorted()` which holds traversal of the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the reason you're seeing some of this behavior depending on where you're sorting your stream is because of the "timing" of data flowing through the stream.

Your foreach is adding them to the list of words that have already been found - but keep in mind that no data is evaluated until the foreach is called.  This means the items are only being added to the list as the entire set flows through the foreach.  Your primary filter that happens before the foreach will likely see some duplication as a result of it trying to filter by the list that doesn't really exist yet.

Sorting is throwing a wrench in the gears of it all because it can hold up the data flow - a list can't be guaranteed to be sorted until every element has been seen.  It's not exactly a terminating operation, but it does delay things until all the elements pass through.  Lazy evaluation is a wonderful thing, but it can be tricky and often you really need to be sure something like sorting is what you want before you go that route.

With all that said, if duplication is what you're trying to avoid, there are better ways to go about it (stream has a `.distinct()` function that will do it nicely for you).

I have written another implementation of what you're trying to do here that produces the following result.

```
abel able bale bela elba 
alger glare lager large regal 
angel angle galen glean lange 
caret carte cater crate trace 
elan lane lean lena neal 
evil levi live veil vile
```

If you would like, I can share this with you - but I get the impression this is for some nature of assignment and you're digging to figure it out on your own.  Good on you if that's the case.

If you'd like some tips or to bounce questions off of someone, feel free to DM me and I'll be happy to help.  After that, I'll edit this post and post the code I've used to generate the block above.

Comment: Thanks for reply i have already found the "best" (I guess by efficiency) algorithm for this problem and attached it in main post. 

I'm still kind of do not understand how the streams underneath are working(I just need to work it out), but after reading some of Java Docs(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) and "primitive" debugging it seems that your conclusion is correct.

Comment: In docs we can see that `sorted()` is `a stateful intermediate operation`, which is described as:
> Stateful operations may need to process the entire input before producing a result. For example, one cannot produce any results from sorting a stream until one has seen all elements of the stream.
So it is blocking traversal for `foreach()` and in my second case this gives weird results.